# nmap results after evading firewall

Tags: firewalls, nmap, scan

I've done an nmap scan on my server with an F5 firewall protecting it.

I used the nmap command `nmap -vvv -f -Pn -mtu 8 -sN -oN nmap-results.txt 192.168.22.102`

I had this result but it seems suspicious. Is this result true, and how can I verify it?

```
PORT      STATE         SERVICE              REASON
1/tcp     open|filtered tcpmux               no-response
3/tcp     open|filtered compressnet          no-response
4/tcp     open|filtered unknown              no-response
6/tcp     open|filtered unknown              no-response
7/tcp     open|filtered echo                 no-response
9/tcp     open|filtered discard              no-response
13/tcp    open|filtered daytime              no-response
17/tcp    open|filtered qotd                 no-response
19/tcp    open|filtered chargen              no-response
20/tcp    open|filtered ftp-data             no-response
21/tcp    open|filtered ftp                  no-response
22/tcp    open|filtered ssh                  no-response
23/tcp    open|filtered telnet               no-response
24/tcp    open|filtered priv-mail            no-response
25/tcp    open|filtered smtp                 no-response
26/tcp    open|filtered rsftp                no-response
30/tcp    open|filtered unknown              no-response
32/tcp    open|filtered unknown              no-response
33/tcp    open|filtered dsp                  no-response
37/tcp    open|filtered time                 no-response
42/tcp    open|filtered nameserver           no-response
43/tcp    open|filtered whois                no-response
49/tcp    open|filtered tacacs               no-response
53/tcp    open|filtered domain               no-response
70/tcp    open|filtered gopher               no-response
79/tcp    open|filtered finger               no-response
80/tcp    open|filtered http                 no-response
81/tcp    open|filtered hosts2-ns            no-response
82/tcp    open|filtered xfer                 no-response
83/tcp    open|filtered mit-ml-dev           no-response
84/tcp    open|filtered ctf                  no-response
85/tcp    open|filtered mit-ml-dev           no-response
88/tcp    open|filtered kerberos-sec         no-response
89/tcp    open|filtered su-mit-tg            no-response
90/tcp    open|filtered dnsix                no-response
99/tcp    open|filtered metagram             no-response
100/tcp   open|filtered newacct              no-response
106/tcp   open|filtered pop3pw               no-response
109/tcp   open|filtered pop2                 no-response
110/tcp   open|filtered pop3                 no-response
111/tcp   open|filtered rpcbind              no-response
113/tcp   open|filtered ident                no-response
119/tcp   open|filtered nntp                 no-response
125/tcp   open|filtered locus-map            no-response
135/tcp   open|filtered msrpc                no-response
139/tcp   open|filtered netbios-ssn          no-response
143/tcp   open|filtered imap                 no-response
144/tcp   open|filtered news                 no-response
146/tcp   open|filtered iso-tp0              no-response
161/tcp   open|filtered snmp                 no-response
163/tcp   open|filtered cmip-man             no-response
179/tcp   open|filtered bgp                  no-response
199/tcp   open|filtered smux                 no-response
211/tcp   open|filtered 914c-g               no-response
212/tcp   open|filtered anet                 no-response
222/tcp   open|filtered rsh-spx              no-response
254/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
255/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
256/tcp   open|filtered fw1-secureremote     no-response
259/tcp   open|filtered esro-gen             no-response
264/tcp   open|filtered bgmp                 no-response
280/tcp   open|filtered http-mgmt            no-response
301/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
306/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
311/tcp   open|filtered asip-webadmin        no-response
340/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
366/tcp   open|filtered odmr                 no-response
389/tcp   open|filtered ldap                 no-response
406/tcp   open|filtered imsp                 no-response
407/tcp   open|filtered timbuktu             no-response
416/tcp   open|filtered silverplatter        no-response
417/tcp   open|filtered onmux                no-response
425/tcp   open|filtered icad-el              no-response
427/tcp   open|filtered svrloc               no-response
443/tcp   open|filtered https                no-response
444/tcp   open|filtered snpp                 no-response
445/tcp   open|filtered microsoft-ds         no-response
458/tcp   open|filtered appleqtc             no-response
464/tcp   open|filtered kpasswd5             no-response
465/tcp   open|filtered smtps                no-response
481/tcp   open|filtered dvs                  no-response
497/tcp   open|filtered retrospect           no-response
500/tcp   open|filtered isakmp               no-response
512/tcp   open|filtered exec                 no-response
513/tcp   open|filtered login                no-response
514/tcp   open|filtered shell                no-response
515/tcp   open|filtered printer              no-response
524/tcp   open|filtered ncp                  no-response
541/tcp   open|filtered uucp-rlogin          no-response
543/tcp   open|filtered klogin               no-response
544/tcp   open|filtered kshell               no-response
545/tcp   open|filtered ekshell              no-response
548/tcp   open|filtered afp                  no-response
554/tcp   open|filtered rtsp                 no-response
555/tcp   open|filtered dsf                  no-response
563/tcp   open|filtered snews                no-response
587/tcp   open|filtered submission           no-response
593/tcp   open|filtered http-rpc-epmap       no-response
616/tcp   open|filtered sco-sysmgr           no-response
617/tcp   open|filtered sco-dtmgr            no-response
625/tcp   open|filtered apple-xsrvr-admin    no-response
631/tcp   open|filtered ipp                  no-response
636/tcp   open|filtered ldapssl              no-response
646/tcp   open|filtered ldp                  no-response
648/tcp   open|filtered rrp                  no-response
666/tcp   open|filtered doom                 no-response
667/tcp   open|filtered disclose             no-response
668/tcp   open|filtered mecomm               no-response
683/tcp   open|filtered corba-iiop           no-response
687/tcp   open|filtered asipregistry         no-response
691/tcp   open|filtered resvc                no-response
700/tcp   open|filtered epp                  no-response
705/tcp   open|filtered agentx               no-response
711/tcp   open|filtered cisco-tdp            no-response
714/tcp   open|filtered iris-xpcs            no-response
720/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
722/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
726/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
749/tcp   open|filtered kerberos-adm         no-response
765/tcp   open|filtered webster              no-response
777/tcp   open|filtered multiling-http       no-response
783/tcp   open|filtered spamassassin         no-response
787/tcp   open|filtered qsc                  no-response
800/tcp   open|filtered mdbs_daemon          no-response
801/tcp   open|filtered device               no-response
808/tcp   open|filtered ccproxy-http         no-response
843/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
873/tcp   open|filtered rsync                no-response
880/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
888/tcp   open|filtered accessbuilder        no-response
898/tcp   open|filtered sun-manageconsole    no-response
900/tcp   open|filtered omginitialrefs       no-response
901/tcp   open|filtered samba-swat           no-response
902/tcp   open|filtered iss-realsecure       no-response
903/tcp   open|filtered iss-console-mgr      no-response
911/tcp   open|filtered xact-backup          no-response
912/tcp   open|filtered apex-mesh            no-response
981/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
987/tcp   open|filtered unknown              no-response
990/tcp   open|filtered ftps                 no-response
992/tcp   open|filtered telnets              no-response
993/tcp   open|filtered imaps                no-response
995/tcp   open|filtered pop3s                no-response
999/tcp   open|filtered garcon               no-response
1000/tcp  open|filtered cadlock              no-response
1001/tcp  open|filtered webpush              no-response
1002/tcp  open|filtered windows-icfw         no-response
1007/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
1009/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
1010/tcp  open|filtered surf                 no-response
1011/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
1021/tcp  open|filtered exp1                 no-response
1022/tcp  open|filtered exp2                 no-response
1023/tcp  open|filtered netvenuechat         no-response
1024/tcp  open|filtered kdm                  no-response
1025/tcp  open|filtered NFS-or-IIS           no-response
1026/tcp  open|filtered LSA-or-nterm         no-response
1027/tcp  open|filtered IIS                  no-response
1028/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
1029/tcp  open|filtered ms-lsa               no-response
1030/tcp  open|filtered iad1                 no-response
1031/tcp  open|filtered iad2                 no-response
1032/tcp  open|filtered iad3                 no-response
1033/tcp  open|filtered netinfo              no-response
1034/tcp  open|filtered zincite-a            no-response
1035/tcp  open|filtered multidropper         no-response
1036/tcp  open|filtered nsstp                no-response
1037/tcp  open|filtered ams                  no-response
1038/tcp  open|filtered mtqp                 no-response
1039/tcp  open|filtered sbl                  no-response
1040/tcp  open|filtered netsaint             no-response
1041/tcp  open|filtered danf-ak2             no-response
1042/tcp  open|filtered afrog                no-response
1043/tcp  open|filtered boinc                no-response
1044/tcp  open|filtered dcutility            no-response
1045/tcp  open|filtered fpitp                no-response
1046/tcp  open|filtered wfremotertm          no-response
1047/tcp  open|filtered neod1                no-response
1048/tcp  open|filtered neod2                no-response
1049/tcp  open|filtered td-postman           no-response
1050/tcp  open|filtered java-or-OTGfileshare no-response
1051/tcp  open|filtered optima-vnet          no-response
1052/tcp  open|filtered ddt                  no-response
1053/tcp  open|filtered remote-as            no-response
1054/tcp  open|filtered brvread              no-response
1055/tcp  open|filtered ansyslmd             no-response
1056/tcp  open|filtered vfo                  no-response
1057/tcp  open|filtered startron             no-response
1058/tcp  open|filtered nim                  no-response
1059/tcp  open|filtered nimreg               no-response
1060/tcp  open|filtered polestar             no-response
1061/tcp  open|filtered kiosk                no-response
1062/tcp  open|filtered veracity             no-response
1063/tcp  open|filtered kyoceranetdev        no-response
1064/tcp  open|filtered jstel                no-response
1065/tcp  open|filtered syscomlan            no-response
1066/tcp  open|filtered fpo-fns              no-response
1067/tcp  open|filtered instl_boots          no-response
1068/tcp  open|filtered instl_bootc          no-response
1069/tcp  open|filtered cognex-insight       no-response
1070/tcp  open|filtered gmrupdateserv        no-response
1071/tcp  open|filtered bsquare-voip         no-response
1072/tcp  open|filtered cardax               no-response
1073/tcp  open|filtered bridgecontrol        no-response
1074/tcp  open|filtered warmspotMgmt         no-response
1075/tcp  open|filtered rdrmshc              no-response
1076/tcp  open|filtered sns_credit           no-response
1077/tcp  open|filtered imgames              no-response
1078/tcp  open|filtered avocent-proxy        no-response
1079/tcp  open|filtered asprovatalk          no-response
1080/tcp  open|filtered socks                no-response
1081/tcp  open|filtered pvuniwien            no-response
1082/tcp  open|filtered amt-esd-prot         no-response
1083/tcp  open|filtered ansoft-lm-1          no-response
1084/tcp  open|filtered ansoft-lm-2          no-response
1085/tcp  open|filtered webobjects           no-response
1086/tcp  open|filtered cplscrambler-lg      no-response
1087/tcp  open|filtered cplscrambler-in      no-response
1088/tcp  open|filtered cplscrambler-al      no-response
1089/tcp  open|filtered ff-annunc            no-response
1090/tcp  open|filtered ff-fms               no-response
1091/tcp  open|filtered ff-sm                no-response
1092/tcp  open|filtered obrpd                no-response
1093/tcp  open|filtered proofd               no-response
1094/tcp  open|filtered rootd                no-response
1095/tcp  open|filtered nicelink             no-response
1096/tcp  open|filtered cnrprotocol          no-response
1097/tcp  open|filtered sunclustermgr        no-response
1098/tcp  open|filtered rmiactivation        no-response
1099/tcp  open|filtered rmiregistry          no-response
1100/tcp  open|filtered mctp                 no-response
1102/tcp  open|filtered adobeserver-1        no-response
1104/tcp  open|filtered xrl                  no-response
1105/tcp  open|filtered ftranhc              no-response
1106/tcp  open|filtered isoipsigport-1       no-response
1107/tcp  open|filtered isoipsigport-2       no-response
1108/tcp  open|filtered ratio-adp            no-response
1110/tcp  open|filtered nfsd-status          no-response
1111/tcp  open|filtered lmsocialserver       no-response
1112/tcp  open|filtered msql                 no-response
1113/tcp  open|filtered ltp-deepspace        no-response
1114/tcp  open|filtered mini-sql             no-response
1117/tcp  open|filtered ardus-mtrns          no-response
1119/tcp  open|filtered bnetgame             no-response
1121/tcp  open|filtered rmpp                 no-response
1122/tcp  open|filtered availant-mgr         no-response
1123/tcp  open|filtered murray               no-response
1124/tcp  open|filtered hpvmmcontrol         no-response
1126/tcp  open|filtered hpvmmdata            no-response
1130/tcp  open|filtered casp                 no-response
1131/tcp  open|filtered caspssl              no-response
1132/tcp  open|filtered kvm-via-ip           no-response
1137/tcp  open|filtered trim                 no-response
1138/tcp  open|filtered encrypted_admin      no-response
1141/tcp  open|filtered mxomss               no-response
1145/tcp  open|filtered x9-icue              no-response
1147/tcp  open|filtered capioverlan          no-response
1148/tcp  open|filtered elfiq-repl           no-response
1149/tcp  open|filtered bvtsonar             no-response
1151/tcp  open|filtered unizensus            no-response
1152/tcp  open|filtered winpoplanmess        no-response
1154/tcp  open|filtered resacommunity        no-response
1163/tcp  open|filtered sddp                 no-response
1164/tcp  open|filtered qsm-proxy            no-response
1165/tcp  open|filtered qsm-gui              no-response
1166/tcp  open|filtered qsm-remote           no-response
1169/tcp  open|filtered tripwire             no-response
1174/tcp  open|filtered fnet-remote-ui       no-response
1175/tcp  open|filtered dossier              no-response
1183/tcp  open|filtered llsurfup-http        no-response
1185/tcp  open|filtered catchpole            no-response
1186/tcp  open|filtered mysql-cluster        no-response
1187/tcp  open|filtered alias                no-response
1192/tcp  open|filtered caids-sensor         no-response
1198/tcp  open|filtered cajo-discovery       no-response
1199/tcp  open|filtered dmidi                no-response
1201/tcp  open|filtered nucleus-sand         no-response
1213/tcp  open|filtered mpc-lifenet          no-response
1216/tcp  open|filtered etebac5              no-response
1217/tcp  open|filtered hpss-ndapi           no-response
1218/tcp  open|filtered aeroflight-ads       no-response
1233/tcp  open|filtered univ-appserver       no-response
1234/tcp  open|filtered hotline              no-response
1236/tcp  open|filtered bvcontrol            no-response
1244/tcp  open|filtered isbconference1       no-response
1247/tcp  open|filtered visionpyramid        no-response
1248/tcp  open|filtered hermes               no-response
1259/tcp  open|filtered opennl-voice         no-response
1271/tcp  open|filtered excw                 no-response
1272/tcp  open|filtered cspmlockmgr          no-response
1277/tcp  open|filtered miva-mqs             no-response
1287/tcp  open|filtered routematch           no-response
1296/tcp  open|filtered dproxy               no-response
1300/tcp  open|filtered h323hostcallsc       no-response
1301/tcp  open|filtered ci3-software-1       no-response
1309/tcp  open|filtered jtag-server          no-response
1310/tcp  open|filtered husky                no-response
1311/tcp  open|filtered rxmon                no-response
1322/tcp  open|filtered novation             no-response
1328/tcp  open|filtered ewall                no-response
1334/tcp  open|filtered writesrv             no-response
1352/tcp  open|filtered lotusnotes           no-response
1417/tcp  open|filtered timbuktu-srv1        no-response
1433/tcp  open|filtered ms-sql-s             no-response
1434/tcp  open|filtered ms-sql-m             no-response
1443/tcp  open|filtered ies-lm               no-response
1455/tcp  open|filtered esl-lm               no-response
1461/tcp  open|filtered ibm_wrless_lan       no-response
1494/tcp  open|filtered citrix-ica           no-response
1500/tcp  open|filtered vlsi-lm              no-response
1501/tcp  open|filtered sas-3                no-response
1503/tcp  open|filtered imtc-mcs             no-response
1521/tcp  open|filtered oracle               no-response
1524/tcp  open|filtered ingreslock           no-response
1533/tcp  open|filtered virtual-places       no-response
1556/tcp  open|filtered veritas_pbx          no-response
1580/tcp  open|filtered tn-tl-r1             no-response
1583/tcp  open|filtered simbaexpress         no-response
1594/tcp  open|filtered sixtrak              no-response
1600/tcp  open|filtered issd                 no-response
1641/tcp  open|filtered invision             no-response
1658/tcp  open|filtered sixnetudr            no-response
1666/tcp  open|filtered netview-aix-6        no-response
1687/tcp  open|filtered nsjtp-ctrl           no-response
1688/tcp  open|filtered nsjtp-data           no-response
1700/tcp  open|filtered mps-raft             no-response
1717/tcp  open|filtered fj-hdnet             no-response
1718/tcp  open|filtered h323gatedisc         no-response
1719/tcp  open|filtered h323gatestat         no-response
1720/tcp  open|filtered h323q931             no-response
1721/tcp  open|filtered caicci               no-response
1723/tcp  open|filtered pptp                 no-response
1755/tcp  open|filtered wms                  no-response
1761/tcp  open|filtered landesk-rc           no-response
1782/tcp  open|filtered hp-hcip              no-response
1783/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
1801/tcp  open|filtered msmq                 no-response
1805/tcp  open|filtered enl-name             no-response
1812/tcp  open|filtered radius               no-response
1839/tcp  open|filtered netopia-vo1          no-response
1840/tcp  open|filtered netopia-vo2          no-response
1862/tcp  open|filtered mysql-cm-agent       no-response
1863/tcp  open|filtered msnp                 no-response
1864/tcp  open|filtered paradym-31           no-response
1875/tcp  open|filtered westell-stats        no-response
1900/tcp  open|filtered upnp                 no-response
1914/tcp  open|filtered elm-momentum         no-response
1935/tcp  open|filtered rtmp                 no-response
1947/tcp  open|filtered sentinelsrm          no-response
1971/tcp  open|filtered netop-school         no-response
1972/tcp  open|filtered intersys-cache       no-response
1974/tcp  open|filtered drp                  no-response
1984/tcp  open|filtered bigbrother           no-response
1998/tcp  open|filtered x25-svc-port         no-response
1999/tcp  open|filtered tcp-id-port          no-response
2000/tcp  open|filtered cisco-sccp           no-response
2001/tcp  open|filtered dc                   no-response
2002/tcp  open|filtered globe                no-response
2003/tcp  open|filtered finger               no-response
2004/tcp  open|filtered mailbox              no-response
2005/tcp  open|filtered deslogin             no-response
2006/tcp  open|filtered invokator            no-response
2007/tcp  open|filtered dectalk              no-response
2008/tcp  open|filtered conf                 no-response
2009/tcp  open|filtered news                 no-response
2010/tcp  open|filtered search               no-response
2013/tcp  open|filtered raid-am              no-response
2020/tcp  open|filtered xinupageserver       no-response
2021/tcp  open|filtered servexec             no-response
2022/tcp  open|filtered down                 no-response
2030/tcp  open|filtered device2              no-response
2033/tcp  open|filtered glogger              no-response
2034/tcp  open|filtered scoremgr             no-response
2035/tcp  open|filtered imsldoc              no-response
2038/tcp  open|filtered objectmanager        no-response
2040/tcp  open|filtered lam                  no-response
2041/tcp  open|filtered interbase            no-response
2042/tcp  open|filtered isis                 no-response
2043/tcp  open|filtered isis-bcast           no-response
2045/tcp  open|filtered cdfunc               no-response
2046/tcp  open|filtered sdfunc               no-response
2047/tcp  open|filtered dls                  no-response
2048/tcp  open|filtered dls-monitor          no-response
2049/tcp  open|filtered nfs                  no-response
2065/tcp  open|filtered dlsrpn               no-response
2068/tcp  open|filtered avocentkvm           no-response
2099/tcp  open|filtered h2250-annex-g        no-response
2100/tcp  open|filtered amiganetfs           no-response
2103/tcp  open|filtered zephyr-clt           no-response
2105/tcp  open|filtered eklogin              no-response
2106/tcp  open|filtered ekshell              no-response
2107/tcp  open|filtered msmq-mgmt            no-response
2111/tcp  open|filtered kx                   no-response
2119/tcp  open|filtered gsigatekeeper        no-response
2121/tcp  open|filtered ccproxy-ftp          no-response
2126/tcp  open|filtered pktcable-cops        no-response
2135/tcp  open|filtered gris                 no-response
2144/tcp  open|filtered lv-ffx               no-response
2160/tcp  open|filtered apc-2160             no-response
2161/tcp  open|filtered apc-agent            no-response
2170/tcp  open|filtered eyetv                no-response
2179/tcp  open|filtered vmrdp                no-response
2190/tcp  open|filtered tivoconnect          no-response
2191/tcp  open|filtered tvbus                no-response
2196/tcp  open|filtered unknown              no-response
2200/tcp  open|filtered ici                  no-response
2222/tcp  open|filtered EtherNetIP-1         no-response
2251/tcp  open|filtered dif-port             no-response
2260/tcp  open|filtered apc-2260             no-response
2288/tcp  open|filtered netml                no-response
2301/tcp  open|filtered compaqdiag           no-response
2323/tcp  open|filtered 3d-nfsd              no-response
2366/tcp  open|filtered qip-login            no-response
2381/tcp  open|filtered compaq-https         no-response
2382/tcp  open|filtered ms-olap3             no-response
2383/tcp  open|filtered ms-olap4             no-response
2393/tcp  open|filtered ms-olap1             no-response
2394/tcp  open|filtered ms-olap2             no-response
2399/tcp  open|filtered fmpro-fdal           no-response
2401/tcp  open|filtered cvspserver           no-response
2492/tcp  open|filtered groove               no-response
2500/tcp  open|filtered rtsserv              no-response
2522/tcp  open|filtered windb                no-response
2525/tcp  open|filtered ms-v-worlds          no-response
2557/tcp  open|filtered nicetec-mgmt         no-response
2601/tcp  open|filtered zebra                no-response
2602/tcp  open|filtered ripd                 no-response
2604/tcp  open|filtered ospfd                no-response
2605/tcp  open|filtered bgpd                 no-response
2607/tcp  open|filtered connection           no-response
2608/tcp  open|filtered wag-service          no-response
2638/tcp  open|filtered sybase               no-response
2701/tcp  open|filtered sms-rcinfo           no-response
2702/tcp  open|filtered sms-xfer             no-response
2710/tcp  open|filtered sso-service          no-response
2717/tcp  open|filtered pn-requester         no-response
2718/tcp  open|filtered pn-requester2        no-response
2725/tcp  open|filtered msolap-ptp2          no-response
2800/tcp  open|filtered acc-raid             no-response
2809/tcp  open|filtered corbaloc             no-response
2811/tcp  open|filtered gsiftp               no-response
2869/tcp  open|filtered icslap               no-response
2875/tcp  open|filtered dxmessagebase2       no-response
2909/tcp  open|filtered funk-dialout         no-response
2910/tcp  open|filtered tdaccess             no-response
2920/tcp  open|filtered roboeda              no-response
2967/tcp  open|filtered symantec-av          no-response
2968/tcp  open|filtered enpp                 no-response
2998/tcp  open|filtered iss-realsec          no-response
3000/tcp  open|filtered ppp                  no-response
```

Comment: how can I get a real results in this case and bypass this portspoof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `-sN` TCP NULL scan option. This scan sends a TCP packet with no flags set; this is an invalid packet. According to the RFC, a system should respond to it with a RST if the port is closed, or drop it if the port is open. However, only some (mostly Unix-derived) systems actually do this. Others respond the same way to every invalid packet: either dropping it or sending a RST.

It looks like your system drops every invalid packet, as evidenced by the `no-response` in the REASON column. So this scan method will not work for this target. In fact, using a modern (post-Nmap) firewall likely makes it impossible to use any of the TCP scan methods besides `-sS` and `-sT`.